# How to set multiple cookies with jQuery cookie plugin in one line?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I have been using the [**jquery Cookie plugin**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for some time. For setting multiple cookies, I usually do like this:

```
$.cookie('cookie1', 'value1');
$.cookie('cookie2', 'value2');
$.cookie('cookie3', 'value3');
```

And for deleting multiple cookies, I usually do like this:

```
$.cookie('cookie1', null);
$.cookie('cookie2', null);
$.cookie('cookie3', null);
```

I just want to know, Is there some way we can do this is one line?? Something like:

```
// For setting multiple cookies
$.cookie({'cookie1', 'value1'},{'cookie2', 'value2'},{'cookie3', 'value2'});

// For deleting multiple cookies
$.cookie({'cookie1', null},{'cookie2', null},{'cookie3', null});
```

Thanks in Advance!

***P.S.*** The above code is just my assumption.

Comment: no, this is not possible with this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think, right at the moment it is not possible. We have to use the plain old way of setting multiple cookies like this:

```
$.cookie('cookie1', 'value1');
$.cookie('cookie2', 'value2');
$.cookie('cookie3', 'value3');
```